# Caching in OPA where data is pulled from external source for eval

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have a pretty common use case where I would like to cache the results of a http.send for a given amount of time. I know I can do something like

```
value := http.send({
    "url": "https://whatever.com",
    "method": "get",
    
    # Cached for one minute
    "force_cache": true,
    "force_cache_duration": 60
})
```

1. Where actually does it cache the returned value. We are running OPA as a k8s side car in the container.
2. How does it determine to use the cache v/s making the rest call.
3. How is the cache invalidated ?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Where actually does it cache the returned value

OPA stores the data in an internal cache, it's in memory and isn't accessible from elsewhere.

> 2. How does it determine to use the cache v/s making the rest call.
> 3. How is the cache invalidated ?

If you are using `force_cache: true` then the value will be retained for as long as the value of `force_cache_duration` in seconds. If `force_cache` is not set, then OPA will use the `Cache-Control` & `Expires` response header values similar to a browser. If the server sets and `Etag` or `Last-Modified` header value, then OPA can also use these to invalidate the cache.

The docs are quite detailed on this topic and might be worth a read too.
https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#http